# Django post save signal timing issue?

Tags: django

**Model.py **

```
class Store(models.Model):
    status_type = (
        ("y",'Yes'),
        ("n","No")
    )
    branch = models.ManyToManyField(Branch)
    asset = models.ForeignKey(AssetTag,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    asset_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique = True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    serial_no = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice_code = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase_date = models.DateField()
    
    store_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = status_type, default = "y", blank = True)
    store_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    store_remark = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None)

    start_warrany = models.DateField(default=None)
    end_warrany = models.DateField(default=None)
    
    emp_id= models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True ,blank=True, default=None)

    assige = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = status_type, default = "n", blank = True)
    assige_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    assige_remark = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None)     

    scrap = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = status_type, default = "n", blank = True)
    scrap_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    scrap_remark = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    

    
def AssetCodeGenerator(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        id = instance
        model_obj = Store.objects.get(id = int(id.id))
        print(model_obj.branch)
        
post_save.connect(AssetCodeGenerator, sender = Store)
```

**View.py**

```
def Add_Store(request): # for Asset add
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            form = StoreForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid:
                store_add = form.save(commit=False)
                store_add.created_by = request.user
                store_add.save()
                form.save_m2m() # for m to m field save
                return redirect('store_page')
```

**Problem is that when run store_add.save() while directly signal is called and then after run form.save_m2m() that's reason signal don't know the m2m data because save() method before run m2m() **